# How to get the right variable to get the right user logged in?

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli, statements

I'am trying to make a PHP login for my university website where I want the user to login with their usernames.

I'm trying this query in mysqli with prepared statements but its giving error like the number of parameters exceed. It's giving the right error and I know that I'm causing any issue/problem somewhere.

```
$user_roll = $_SESSION['roll'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
    SELECT roll, name, course, semester FROM students WHERE roll = ?
"); 
$stmt->bind_param('isssi',$roll,$name,$course,$semester,$user_roll);
```

Comment: you are mixing up [`->bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and [`bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php) syntax

Comment: Sean is correct. don't mix both

Comment: You are binding too many variables. You only need to bind `$user_role`

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It just got it fixed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a mix of [`->bind_param()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) and [`bind_result()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php). You only need the 1 param (`$user_roll`) in `->bind_param()`, and the others will be used in `->bind_result()` after your `->execute()`, for example -

```
$user_roll = $_SESSION['roll'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT roll, name, course, semester FROM students WHERE roll = ?"); 
$stmt->bind_param('i',$user_roll);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($roll,$name,$course,$semester);
while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo $roll."<br />";
    echo $name."<br />";
    echo $course."<br />";
    echo $semester;
}
```

Comment: You are right. This code is correct. It just fixed up everything. Thank you guys, you all :)